# Pasar valores de bootstrap a PHP

Tags: php, bootstrap

Me he descargado una plantilla con bootstrap en la cual hay una parte tipo FORM que consta de lo siguiente:

```
<div class="share-desc">
  <div class="share">
   <p>Number of units :</p><input type="number" class="text_box" type="text" value="1" min="1" />               
  </div>
  <div class="button"><span><a href="#">Add to Cart</a></span></div>                    
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Para enviar los valores seleccionados y los datos del producto he intentado hacer esto:

```
<from action="carro/prueb1.php" method="POST">
   <div class="share-desc">
      <div class="share">
        <p>Numero de Unidades :</p><input type="number" class="text_box" type="text" value="1" min="1" id="num" />
      </div>
      <div class="button" type="submit" name="btn"><span><a>Añadir al Carro</a></span></div>         
      <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
</from>
```

De momento en PHP tengo esto :

```
<?php
 include('../Conector'); 
 $conexion=conectar('bbdd');
 //extract($_REQUEST);
 session_start();
  if ( !isset($_SESSION['btn'])){

       echo "<h2> Mensaje </h2>";
    }else{
        $uni=$_POST['num'];
        echo "<h2>".$uni."</h2>";  
    }
?>
```

Quiero alterar lo menos posible el código de la plantilla bootstrap, pero a la vez necesito que me funcione el envió de valores, cosa que de momento no he conseguido .
He trabajado poco con bootstrap , de ahí mi pregunta

Qué debo hacer para pasar los valores a PHP?

Comment: Al final para no complicarme más de la cuenta , he decidido sacrificar el  dieseño y poner  <button> o <input type="submit">.<br> Gracias a Todos por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para complementar la respuesta de Error404, el atributo `type` no es válido en la etiqueta `<div>` por lo cual probablemente no tenga ningún efecto para el envío del formulario.

Ver la documentación de `<div>` en MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/div

---

Lo ideal sería que usaras la etiqueta `<button>` o `<input type="submit">.`

Teniendo en cuenta que no quieres modificar el html, la única opción que tienes es JavaScript, algo así podría funcionar:

```
// tu form no tiene ningún id o clase, asumiendo que es el primer form del documento
var form = document.forms[0];

// enviar el formulario al hacer clic en el primer elemento con la clase "button" 
form.getElementsByClassName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
  form.submit();
});
```

Comment: el atributo type estaba en la plantilla , no es cosa de @Error404

Comment: @Gabriel Realmente lo del type te lo indiqué en un comentario aunque estaba esperando tu respuesta :D

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que indicar en tu input el attributo `name`:

```
<input type="number" class="text_box" type="text" value="1" min="1" id="num" name="num" />
```

De esta manera, al recuperar los datos, puedes hacer `$_POST['num']`.

Comment: Gracias @Error404 el problema esta en el boton. El name lo he puesto y nada

Comment: @Gabriel Creo que el problema está en que estás usando un div para crear el botón del formulario. Intenta usar `<input type="submit"` en vez del div.